# Different results returned between SUM()/total rows and AVG() in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sum, average

I have a table #time_per_bike with 6549 rows (no duplicates present. Even the bikeid column has unique IDs). Please see the sample -

[image: Sample Data]

Can anybody tell me why am I getting different results between the two queries (since I believe they do same operation. Please correct me if I am wrong)?

```
select SUM(AVG_WAIT_TIME)/6549 from #time_per_bike
-- Returns 69499

select AVG(AVG_WAIT_TIME) from #time_per_bike
-- Returns 69520
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "Except for the COUNT(*) function, all aggregate functions perform a
>   Null-elimination step, so that Null values are not included in the
>   final result of the calculation." Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)

So you have some `NULL`s present in your data.

You have two choices depending how you want to treat nulls in your data. You can either treat as a zero value, or eliminate the rows entirely so they won't contribute to COUNT(*) (as `AVG()` does).

From referenced wiki page:

> For example, in the following table, AVG(i) (the average of the values
>   of i) will give a different result from that of AVG(j):
>
> ```
> Table
> i         j
> 150     150
> 200     200
> 250     250
> NULL      0
> ```
>
> Here AVG(i) is 200 (the average of 150, 200, and 250), while AVG(j) is
>   150 (the average of 150, 200, 250, and 0).
>
> A well-known side effect of
>   this is that in SQL AVG(z) is not equivalent with SUM(z)/COUNT(*)

Comment: You are right @Mitch. I have two AVG_WAIT_TIME with NULLS. So in this case, which would be the correct avg? I guess the one with AVG()

Comment: Well, it entirely depends how you want to treat nulls in your data. You can either treat as a zero value, or eliminate the rows entirely (so they won't contribute to COUNT(*))

Comment: Thanks, I will better update those two nulls with 0 and take the avg.

Comment: rather than update the rows might be better to create a view with  a CASE statement to translate NULLs into zeros

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mitch

select AVG(case when AVG_WAIT_TIME is NULL then 0 else AVG_WAIT_TIME end) from #time_per_bike